# Use Now function in ORM queries

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework

Is it possible to generate SQL queries by ORM that use NOW function from database? For example:

```
select * from Order where OrderDate > Now() - Interval 1 Day

insert into Orders Set OrderDate = Now()
```

I am primarily interested in NHibernate and Entity Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use [example queries](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-examples) for dialect-specific functions because the properties will not match the desired types (if `OrderDate` is a `DateTime` there is no way to specify `Now() - Interval 1 Day` as a `DateTime`).

If you have the dialect-specific functions defined (I believe you can use the techniques described at http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2011/06/14/adding-custom-sql-functions-to-nhibernate-at-runtime.aspx) you may be able to use [Criteria queries](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-criteria).